# prevent unnecessary class files being loaded with spl_autoload_register

Tags: php

I have a fair few class files in a directory, `_classes`, that I want to split up in order to prevent them all from being loaded unnecessarily. The way I would like it to work is for all class files within the directory `_classes/xs` to be loaded via `spl_autoload_register()`. Then, any class files within the directory `_classes/static` need to be loaded manually.

I have already made the new directories and moved all the files into their relevant folder, but when I use `spl_autoload_register()`, it will also try including files from `/static` even though I've pointed to `xs`.

---

## Code

`init.php`:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class){
    require_once "_classes/xs/" . $class . ".php";
});
```

`example.php`:

```
require_once "init.php";
require_once "_classes/static/Class.php";
```

---

## Error

> **Warning**: require_once(_classes/xs/Class.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **init.php**

So all the files in `xs` are loading correctly, but it's also attempting to retrieve the files from `static` (which it shouldn't be).

All help is appreciated, cheers.

Comment: Do you use namespaces and if so do you `use` the correct namespace for `Class`?

Comment: @NigelRen No I don't. It's one thing I never properly got around to learning how to use. What is the correct namespace for `Class` and how would I implement it? :)

Comment: The namespace for any particular class is something you would normally decide - almost like the directory structure you store the files in.  Have a read of https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php for more information.

Comment: @NigelRen feel free to make an answer if you believe it might solve my problem :) Might earn you an extra 25 points hah

Comment: Trying to reproduce your problems is proving difficult - If I `require_once` a file with the class defined and then create an instance of that class, then it's doesn't throw the error.  Can you show a very simple example of Class.php and a test line which creates the object ( `$a = new Test();` for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't usually use [require_once()](https://secure.php.net/require_once) for autoloader because the file might not be there at all.

In your case, simply change to [include_once()](https://secure.php.net/include_once) should fix it:

init.php

```php
spl_autoload_register(function($class){
    if (file_exists("_classes/xs/" . $class . ".php")) {
        include_once "_classes/xs/" . $class . ".php";
    }
});
```

---

**Side Note:**

I originally used `@` sign to suppress error instead of `file_exists` check because I think it would be more performant. But to my surprise, the `file_exists` call version is actually much faster to run.

```php
<?php

$scale = 1000000;

function benchmark(callable $fn, $scale = 100) {
        $start = microtime(1);
        for ($i=0; $i<$scale; $i++) {
                $fn();
        }
        return microtime(1) - $start;
}

$time = benchmark(function () {
        $file = './no-such-file.php';
        if (file_exists($file)) {
                include_once $file;
        }
}, $scale);
printf("file_exists:   %0.6fs\n", $time);

$time = benchmark(function () {
        $file = './no-such-file.php';
        @include_once $file;
}, $scale);
printf("@include_once: %0.6fs\n", $time);
```

Result (on PHP 7.2):

```
file_exists:   1.067368s
@include_once: 8.830794s
```

Comment: If your not sure if a file exists - use [`file_exists()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) rather than this fudge.  Especially using `@` is definitely not a good way of getting round a simple test.

Comment: I used `@` sign because I think adding additional `file_exists`might be slower. They're both checking the file existence anyway.

Comment: Anyway, I'm changing to `file_exists`.

Comment: Marked as the result because of how much effort you went through to benchmark - and actually corrected yourself. Props to you :)